# Fetch and Update Nested JSON attribute value

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I have a nested JSON which looks like this.

```
{
"eventId" : "12345",
"eventName" : "carnival",
"object": {
    "objectId" : "5678",
    "objectFiles" : [{"fileName":"text.txt", "fileContent":"This is a test file."},
                    {"fileName":"text2.txt", "fileContent":"This is a test2 file."}]
    }
}
```

Here I have to fetch the eventFiles key, replace the fileContent value with Base64Encoded String and place it back to the same eventFiles attribute. I know that I can use Jackson Mapper to convert it into Map and iterate them one by one, untill I find eventFiles key, then fetch and replace the value and store it back again. I tried to convert it as a Map using `TypeReference<String, Object>` or even `TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>` but the problem here is the nested JSON where ultimately it would become Map inside of a Map inside of a Map which would become pretty complex to handle.

Is there any other simpler way to accomplish this? Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If your Json has a fixed format you can use Gson (https://github.com/google/gson) and convert it to an Object that represent your json.

It would look something like this:

```
public class CustomEvent {
    String eventId;
    String eventName;
    CustomObject object;
}

public class CustomObject {
    String objectId;
    List<CustomFile> objectFiles;
}

public class CustomFile {
    String fileName;
    String fileContent;
}
```

And you could use it like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
CustomEvent event = gson.fromJson(yourString, Event.class)
// Do whatever you want with the event

String modifiedJson = gson.toJson(event);
```

Hope it helped

Comment: thanks for your answer. I would not have a fixed format. It keeps changing. So dynamically I have to accomplish this.